# Bootstrap UI Datepicker Popup not working after 2.1.4 update

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have the following code snippet that was working fine in my web application utilising the Bootstrap UI library v0.14.3:

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="dateSelection">Reporting Period:</label>
    <div class="input-group input-group-sm right-align">
        <input 
            id="dateSelection" 
            type="text" 
            class="form-control" 
            uib-datepicker-popup="{{ format }}" 
            popup-placement="bottom-right" 
            ng-model="date" 
            is-open="Calendar.opened" 
            datepicker-options="calendarOptions" 
            ng-required="true" 
            close-text="Close" 
            on-open-focus="false" 
            ng-change="chooseCustomDate( date )" 
            ng-disabled="true" />
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button 
                        type="button" 
                        class="btn btn-default" 
                        ng-click="openCalendar()">
                        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                    </button>
                </span>
    </div>

</div>
```

Controller:

```
        var yesterdayDate = moment().subtract( 1, 'days' );
        $scope.selectedDate = $filter('date')( new Date( yesterdayDate ), 'yyyy-MM-dd' );
        $scope.forecastVarianceErrors = [];
        $scope.LBossVarianceErrors = [];
        $scope.PortalDifferenceErrors = [];
        $scope.date = $scope.selectedDate;
        $scope.dtInstance = {};
        $scope.showPortalDifferences = true;
        $scope.showLBossVariances = true;
        $scope.showForecastVariances = false;
        $scope.format = 'EEEE, d MMMM, yyyy';


        /*
         * Reporting Period
         *
         */
        $scope.chooseCustomDate = function( date ) {

            // Set the new date
            $scope.selectedDate = $filter('date')( new Date( date ), 'yyyy-MM-dd' );

            // Empty the variance arrays
            $scope.forecastVarianceErrors = [];
            $scope.LBossVarianceErrors = [];
            $scope.PortalDifferenceErrors = [];

            // Redraw the datatable
            $scope.dtInstance.reloadData();

        };


        $scope.openCalendar = function() {

            $scope.Calendar.opened = true;

        };


        $scope.Calendar = {

            opened: false

        };


        $scope.calendarOptions = {
            startingDay: 1  
        };
```

However, recently I required a feature to the Bootstrap UI's Popover element that was only available in `v2.1.4` so I decided to make the transition to the latest version.

After updating, I noticed that all of my `Datepicker Popups` have now stopped working.  I don't receive any errors, just simply the popup never seems to open. I am struggling to find information on what may have changed to see if I am now missing something, or need to alter my code in any way.

If I revert back to v0.14.3, my Datepicker Popups will start working again.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it seems that I was the cause of my own demise.
Within my control, I added the `ng-disabled` tag to the `<input>` field to prevent any user from manually tampering with the date string.  This seemed to be an allowed behaviour of v0.14.3, however, v2.1.4 was not so accommodating.

By changing the `ng-disabled` to a `readonly` tag, it allowed the calendar control to once again be drawn.

Also I found that v2.1.4 wants `new Date();` specified for the `ng-model` or it fails to render the date string within the `<input>` field.